# SharePoint 2013 customize Discussion board View Layout and style

Tags: css, sharepoint, layout, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-discussion-board

I  have been searching for a while now on how can i modify the Discussion board look'n feel. E.g. Styles Css Html in views etc...

My client wants to have the discussion functionnalities on his site, but he wants to change significantly the look'n feel of the Discussion, obviously the layouts and style of the view ...

I was wondering if there is any way to do this since i am using a list based on discussion board template created from Visual studio...

Any help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution can be using JsLink (new in SharePoint 2k13) it is an alternative to `xsl` you can have your board list and customize your display template as far as you want to...

Hope this helps